# Is it possible to ping a glue entry even if your own dns server is down?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, glue-record

I wanted to host my DNS name server at ns1.foo.com (a tiny Linux box with bind9 on it) and for that I added the glue
records (inside domain registrar account) for it, like

```
ns1.foo.com --> 111.111.111.111
```

Now, whenever I tried to ping the ns1.foo.com from console I got "name resolution failure"
or similar.

The moment I started the DNS server (located at 111.111.111.111) daemon the ping started to work.

So the question might put differently as: Are not glue records suppose to be "ping"-able
when created - even if at the IP they refer to there is a DNS server or not?

Comment: `ping` is almost never a good troubleshooting tools. The fact that a nameserver exist and the fact that an entry is written in some zone and is considered to be a glue record has exactly 0 relationship with the host responding to ICMP traffic (aka ping). If you want to troubleshoot or understand how the DNS works you need to do DNS query and for that `dig` is the relevant tool.

Answer (score 0):

When ping makes a DNS query for `ns1.example.com`, it requests A record for `ns1.example.com`.

Glue records only tell the IP address of the DNS server that can respond to `example.com` zone DNS queries, including the A record query.

So the answer is no, glue record IP addresses are not supposed to be pingable.

Comment: So glue records names do not "resolve" to glue records IP, only point the ping program to the DNS server IP that might answer, right?

Comment: Not really. Ping uses operating system's DNS resolver function to ask A record for `ns1.example.com`. Operating system DNS resolver then sends DNS query to your configured name server. The name server sends the query further in the DNS system, finally ending up to `ns1.example.com`, which then returns the A record for `ns1.example.com`.

Comment: So glue records do not count as an A entry for ns1.example.com thus they are not resolved to an IP by a normal program but they are used "internally" by DNS system to find the location of the DNS in charge for a certain domain(s).

Comment: `A` and/or `AAAA` records, depending on OS settings.

Comment: "So the answer is no, glue records are not supposed to be pingable." This is neither true or false, because the two parts are not related at all.

Comment: glue records ARE `A` and `AAAA` records. Their names does not come from their type or their format, but just the fact that they reside in the parent zone, not the child one. @Alex based on your question, you are probably misunderstanding the DNS and the use of glue records.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You supposed to much. I do understand DNS, I'm simply confused about some facts about glue records. If you really want to help me (and other in my situation) please post an answer with the steps a ping to a glue record is (trying to be) resolved. Nothing beats a clear explanation!

Comment: @Alex "the steps a ping to a glue record" Sorry, I still do not understand why you want to "ping" anything DNS related. `ping` is not a good troubleshooting tool (see my other comment), if you want to test something do DNS queries like with `dig`. The fact that a host is "pingable" is unrelated to the fact it is a nameserver or not, or appears as a glue record or not. I would be happy to write a proper answer, but I do not understand your question for now. Besides, you obfuscated stuff instead of giving real names, so not even sure what you are looking it exactly.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The whole problem appeared when I was trying to add some new glue records for a domain for which I had not yet configured the custom DNS server. All I wanted was to see if those glue records resolve to an IP and the first idea that came to my mind was to use ping.